# LinearLayout - How to align 2 textviews at runtime in conversation style

Tags: android, listview, alignment

I'm currently having some problem with LinearLayout. I have this layout for the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/threadBody"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    android:paddingStart="10sp"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_green"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/threadDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
    android:text="@string/date"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

it will show something like this:

[image]

at run time I have this Adapter to turn the listview into conversation:

```
public class ThreadAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {
private Context ctx;
public ArrayList<Message> messageListArray;

public ThreadAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Message> messageListArray) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    this.messageListArray = messageListArray;
    this.ctx = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Holder holder; // holds the two TextView for better scrolling
    View convertView1 = convertView;
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView1 == null) {
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView1 = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item_right, parent,
                false);
        holder.messageContent = (TextView) convertView1
                .findViewById(R.id.threadBody);
        holder.date = (TextView) convertView1.findViewById(R.id.threadDate);
        convertView1.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView1.getTag();
    }
    Message message = getItem(position);
    holder.wrapper = (LinearLayout) convertView1
            .findViewById(R.id.parent_wrapper);
    try {
        if (message.messageNumber.equals("Me")) {
            holder.messageContent
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_sent);
            holder.messageContent.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.END);
        } else {
            holder.messageContent
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_received);
            holder.messageContent.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    holder.messageContent.setText(message.messageContent);
    holder.date.setText(message.messageDate);
    holder.messageContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.date.getVisibility() == TextView.INVISIBLE) {
                holder.date.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.date.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView1;
}

/**
 * @effects returns the size of the array of adapter
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return messageListArray.size();
}

/**
 * @effects returns the item at specific position
 */
@Override
public Message getItem(int position) {
    return messageListArray.get(position);
}

/**
 * @effects set the given list as the default list of the adapter
 * @param messageList
 */
public void setArrayList(ArrayList<Message> messageList) {
    this.messageListArray = messageList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItem(Message msg) {
    this.messageListArray.add(msg);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class Holder {
    public TextView messageContent, date;
    public LinearLayout wrapper;
}
}
```

it would end up like this

[image]

is it possible to align the two textviews at runtime so I have the sent message to be like this without changing the LinearLayout?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make following changes:
layout/list_view_item_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent_wrapper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/threadBody"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="10sp"
android:paddingRight="10sp"
android:paddingStart="10sp"
android:background="@drawable/bubble_green"
android:text="@string/hello_world" />


</LinearLayout>
```

layout/list_view_item_date.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/threadDate"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="10sp"
android:paddingRight="10sp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
android:text="@string/date"
android:textColor="#808080"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:textSize="12sp" />
```

updated code:

```
public class ThreadAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {
private Context ctx;
public ArrayList<Message> messageListArray;

public ThreadAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Message> messageListArray) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    this.messageListArray = messageListArray;
    this.ctx = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Holder holder; // holds the two TextView for better scrolling
    View convertView1 = convertView;
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Message message = getItem(position);
    if (convertView1 == null) {
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView1 = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item_right, parent,
                false);
       LinearLayout wrapper= (LinearLayout) convertView1.findViewById(R.id.parent_wrapper);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item_date,null);
        if(message.messageNumber.equals("Me")){
         wrapper.addView(view,0);
        }else{
         wrapper.addView(view,1);
        }

        holder.messageContent = (TextView) convertView1
                .findViewById(R.id.threadBody);
        holder.date = (TextView) convertView1.findViewById(R.id.threadDate);
        convertView1.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView1.getTag();
    }

    holder.wrapper = (LinearLayout) convertView1
            .findViewById(R.id.parent_wrapper);
    try {
        if (message.messageNumber.equals("Me")) {
            holder.messageContent
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_sent);
            holder.messageContent.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.END);
        } else {
            holder.messageContent
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_received);
            holder.messageContent.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    holder.messageContent.setText(message.messageContent);
    holder.date.setText(message.messageDate);
    holder.messageContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.date.getVisibility() == TextView.INVISIBLE) {
                holder.date.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.date.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView1;
}

/**
 * @effects returns the size of the array of adapter
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return messageListArray.size();
}

/**
 * @effects returns the item at specific position
 */
@Override
public Message getItem(int position) {
    return messageListArray.get(position);
}

/**
 * @effects set the given list as the default list of the adapter
 * @param messageList
 */
public void setArrayList(ArrayList<Message> messageList) {
    this.messageListArray = messageList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItem(Message msg) {
    this.messageListArray.add(msg);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class Holder {
    public TextView messageContent, date;
    public LinearLayout wrapper;
}
}
```

Hope this works...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but thats not what I mean. The condition in my getView works fine, I need to re-align the position of date and message body. If the message is from me then I need it to show before the message, otherwise it will show after the message.

Comment: I end up using vertical layout and put the date below the message, because I can't find a way to balance both the textview horizontally (if the message is too long then the date will be pushed out of the screen; I tried layout_weight but it make the bubble stretch even if the message is short). Anyway thank you for your answers, I upvoted them.